# Are there any differences between Java's "synchronized" and C#'s "lock"?

Tags: c#, java, synchronization

Do these two keywords have exactly the same effect, or is there something I should be aware of?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to this site: http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ:_What_is_the_difference_between_CSharp_lock_and_Java_synchronized, C# `lock` and Java `synchronized` code blocks are "semantically identical", while for methods, Java uses `synchronized` while C# uses an attribute: `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`.

Comment: Nope, "semantically identical" is what I needed to hear... and whether there were any "gotchas", but that page seems to be pretty clear. Thanks. Stackoverflow is my new Google. ;)

Comment: Page doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 6):

One interesting difference not covered in the link posted by Keeg: as far as I'm aware, there's no equivalent *method* calls in Java for .NET's [Monitor.Enter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.enter.aspx) and [Monitor.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.exit.aspx), which the C# `lock` statement boils down to. That means you can't do the equivalent of [Monitor.TryEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.tryenter.aspx) either - although of course the java.util.concurrent.locks package (as of 1.5) has a variety of locks which have more features available.

Answer (score -1):

I java you don't have to worry about locking public types that you own.

In .NET, you [have to](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=f9a1d4c8-553b-4cc1-b1d6-0a8c395d8e9c)

Updated: this is for types that you own. Locking on public types that you don't own is bad in any language :)

Comment: No, it's still a bad idea to lock on public references in Java too. What makes you think it's okay in Java?

Comment: While an interesting link, it absoltely (and statedly) does not discuss the issue of locking public types. Which do I agree you shouldn't do... it is a shame that is how [MethodImpl] does it...

Comment: lock on something public and wait for an idiot to put a deadlocking lock on it too.

Comment: The only reason I can think of that locking on public types in Java may be safe, is perhaps it doesn't have the same "aggressive teardowns" of the app domain that a .net hosting environment (such as in SQL server) may do.  In that case, the risk of orphaned locks wouldn't be as great (or even possible) in Java?  I'm speculating.